# Loading tiff images in fiftyone using ipynp

Tags: python, tiff, fiftyone

I am trying to load tiff images using fiftyone and python in ipynb notebook, but it just doesn't work. Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The images types that FiftyOne supports are [based on the underlying support of the browser you are using to run FiftyOne](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/faq/index.html#what-image-file-types-are-supported). TIFF is only supported out of the box by a few browsers like Safari: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support

For other browsers, you will need to check if there is an extension that adds TIFF support, like this one for Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tiff-viewer/